# How do you remove square brackets in python easily

Tags: python, list, brackets

I have a basic list 
EG : Test1 = []
then i used .append to add to it and fore EG it became:
Test1 = ["hahaha", "lalalal", "mamama"]

at the end i print out the list but of course the brackets are there
i checked other posts like this and didn't really understand could someone show
me how it is done ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want them on the same line:

Via `for` loop.

```
for x in ["hahaha", "lalalal", "mamma"]:
    print(x, end=" ")
```

Or with `str.join`.

```
print(' '.join(["hahaha", "lalalal", "mamma"]))
```

**Output**

```
hahaha lalalal mamama
```

Or on different lines:

```
for x in ["hahaha", "lalalal", "mamma"]:
    print(x)
```

**Output**

```
hahaha
lalalal
mamama
```

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for :) thanks for the help !

Comment: @Taka If this solved your question please mark it the "best answer" by clicking the green checkmark under the voting :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the list as a string with a separating character (like a comma) you would use the `join` method of a string:

```
','.join(["hahaha", "lalalal", "mamma"])
```

Answer (score 0):

in 1 line:

```
Test1 = ["hahaha", "lalalal", "mamama"]
print(", ".join(Test1))
```

join fucntion can join multiple values using separator (and returns string):

```
"separator".join(values)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.